# How to omit named files from created file list in batch

Tags: windows

When stored in the same directory the  .bat file below creates a text file list of all files in the directory. This works fine except it also lists the .bat file itself, and the created List.txt file.
How would I omit named files from the list.

```
(for %%f in (*.*) do @echo %%f) > List.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if not` conditions to exclude things from the loop

This would exclude the *List.txt* file and any *.bat* file:

```
(for %%f in (*.*) do @if not "%%f"=="List.txt" if not "%%~xf"==".bat" echo %%f) > List.txt
```

Comment: I myself would have checked it against `%~dp0` .. that's what I do when operating on everything but the batch itself.

Comment: But he wants to excuse the result file (which is there from last run) as well.

Comment: @Yisoel Tech....Yes, it was adding both the bat and generated txt file. Thank you.